# make a Variable with Subscript in Mathematica

Tags: variables, math, wolfram-mathematica

I'm very new to Mathematica and I need Mathematica to treat the Pmax in `Subscript[P, max] = 12 "kW"` as a single variable. That is because I have a lot more of these like Pmotor and P1, P2 and so on, I want to keep it clear and Simple.
I tried `Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["P", "max"]]]` but I don't get it to work properly... When I define Pmax the "P" is black but the "max" is still blue which I think means its a undefined Variable?
can I tell Mathematica to treat Subscripted Variables as single variables?

Comment: You are going down a path that is possible but almost certainly undesirable.  From what you wrote, it looks like you could use an association.

Comment: you should show example code so folks can see what you are trying to do and what exactly doesn't work. That said @Alan is right you should avoid introducing such complexity just for the sake of making things pretty.

Comment: ok i can understand that, i was going to use mathematica to create a paper for my university but for now i will just use it for calculation with use normal variables.
thanks you guys anyways!!

Comment: Did you load the Notation package? fyi - https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9552/363

Comment: yup, but i might had wrong order when running a fresh session

Comment: Take mathcad 15 or SmathStudio and do your work freely without stupid mma constraints on each step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo using Notation.  Once your notebook is set up as below it can be rerun in a fresh session quickly, all in one go (although the first line is then superfluous).

[image]